# ASP.NET MVC Kendo window popup

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, popupwindow

I am new to Kendo UI. I am creating a popup window using [Kendo UI](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/window). I am able to create and showing a Kendo window as popup with custom width and height. For now it is working fine. But when I am trying to create a popup window (Child window) in a popup window (Parent window), I am not able to apply the custom width and height.

My code as follows:

**Parent window:**

```
<div id="kendopopupAddContact" style="display: none;">
                @{ 
                    @(Html.Kendo().Window()
                .Name("window_AddContact")
                .Width(1000)
                .Events(e => e
                    .Close("ContactWindow_close")
  )
               )   
                }
            </div>
```

**Child window:**

```
 <div id="kendoPopupAddCompany" style="display: none;">
        @{ 
            @(Html.Kendo().Window()
                .Name("addCompanyPopup")
                .Width(280).HtmlAttributes(new {@style="width: 280px !important"})
                .Events(e => e
                    .Close("addCompanyPopup_close")
                    )
               )   
        }
    </div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

There is not such concept of *child* window. Please read [this](http://www.kendoui.com/forums/ui/window/kendowindow-appendto-boundaries.aspx).